# Need to delete part of string from one word to the end in MySQL

Tags: mysql

OK I have trouble and I dont know where else to look. I have a database with a table called "tasks". In this is a column called "description" with fields involving strings.

These descriptions are pretty long, and each one has this format:
      1                       2                               3
Unique description        "But I'd like to remind you..."        Unique text

I need to delete the second part from every description to the end of the string.

So I need an sql query that will delete only the part of each field that starts with "But I'd like to remind you..." until the end of the string,  leaving ONLY part 1, the unique description.

Answer (score 1):

The [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function is good for this sort of thing:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, ' "But I''d', 1)
FROM tasks
```

The second argument is the string you're looking for. The third argument of `1` means return everything *before* the first occurrence of the string you're looking for.

I've included just the first part of the `But I'd like to remind you...` text. You can include as much of it as needed to make sure you get a proper hit.

The query above will return the first part of the description. To update the table and remove everything from `But I'd like to remind you...` to the end, just put the expression into an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tasks
SET description = SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, ' "But I''d', 1)
```

Comment: Ahh that is working great.  I got heidisql to display the text I need,  now I just need to figure out how to replace the text in the database itself.

Comment: I need to use this to update the database itself,  what do I do? I cant figure it out

Comment: Sorry - often when people say "delete the text" they mean "leave it alone but don't show it in the output". I've added an `UPDATE` query to my answer. Try this *on a copy of your data* (not the original - you don't want to lose data if it doesn't work right) and see if it does what you want.